# SQL Server Stored Procedure - If Count( ) Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a stored procedure for SQL Server. I have a working version but I'm looking to optimize it a little bit if possible so that I don't need to waste two calls to the database.

Here is my version :

```
If Exists (Select * From webapi.dbo.Users Where Username=@Username)
Begin
    Select * From webapi.dbo.Users Where Username=@Username
End
Else
Begin
    Set @error_message = 'Username ' + @Username + ' does not exist.'
    Raiserror (@error_message, 16, 1)
End
```

I want something like :

```
Set @User = (Select * From webapi.dbo.Users Where Username=@Username)
If Count(@User) =
    Begin
        Set @error_message = 'Username ' + @Username + ' does not exist.'
        Raiserror (@error_message, 16, 1)
    End
Else
    Begin
        return @User
    End
```

Is this possible or a smart thing to do? I clearly make 2 of the same calls and would like to remove one of them in order to create the fastest possible system and for my own knowledge of SQL.

**I Ended up using:**

```
Select * From webapi.dbo.Users Where Username=@Username
If @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    Begin
        Set @error_message = 'Username ' + @Username + ' does not exist.'
        Raiserror (@error_message, 16, 1)       
    End
```

Comment: If you have an index on `webapi.dbo.users(username)` the calls will be very fast.  You would gain very little in performance by trying to eliminate one of them.

Comment: What do you mean an Index? Like a column named "Id" which would be an int and auto incremement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot store your select result in a classical variable because it's a row, not a field.

For your information if you only need to get 1 field, you could do what you thought with `@@ROWCOUNT`:

```
DECLARE @var INT; 

SELECT @var = id FROM tableName WHERE condition...;
```

After this select ask for `@@ROWCOUNT`

```
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 BEGIN 
RAISERROR... 
END
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this?

```
declare @Username varchar(50) = 'johnny'

if not exists (select 1 from users where username = @username) 
raiserror ('%s does not exist',16,1,@username)
```

`T-SQL` example

Comment: Could be useful, See my edit above for what I ended up using.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you want but little optimize than yours :

```
 If Exists (Select 1 From webapi.dbo.Users Where Username=@Username)
    Begin
        Set @error_message = 'Username ' + @Username + ' does not exist.'
        Raiserror (@error_message, 16, 1)
    End
Else
    Begin
        Select * From webapi.dbo.Users Where Username=@Username
    End
```

Instead of using `*` you can use simply 1 to check condition.

Comment: Seems to still make "2" calls to the DB which I don't want

Comment: select * and select 1 makes no difference. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1

Answer (score 0):

How come you need to "raiserror" in the database if you're concerned about your round trips.  Just hit the database for UserId or UserName

```
select @userid = userid from users where username = @username
```

and if that variable comes back null, just raise that error at the application tier....

I'm actually not sure what you mean by "two calls" to the database. The solution you've decided to go with uses "two calls" just the same. I think there's a bit of confusion here. In your definition of "call", your "if @@rowcount" would be considered a call.

Why not just

```
if not exists (select * from user where username = @username)
  raiserror('no user',16,1)
```

Comment: Is it not good practice to raiserror's? I just thought it would be easier to raise it in the database level, but I can do it in the database access layer too..